# Justification for a string returned by Regex.Split

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have been trying to split a string based on regions enclosed by non escaped quotes, and those between two such substrings.

I have used

```
var parts = Regex.Split(value, "(\"(?:((\\\\\\\\)*\\\\\\\")|[^\"])*\")");
```

Now suppose value is

```
"\"abc\", \"a\\\"b\\\"c\""
```

parts contains

```
""
"\"abc\""
", "
"\"a\\\"b\\\"c\""
"\\\""
""
```

I am unable to figure out why the fifth string is there. Its content is present only inside the contents of the fourth string. Am I using the regex wrong? What is the origin of the string?

Comment: have you considered using the string.Split function? also when this string is split int an array are you expecting to contain the `"\"` or just have a string[] that each index will have the `abc, a, b,c` for example

Comment: I am expecting the escaped characters. You could think of it as a file containing multiple multiple strings contained in double quotes, seperated by commas, some of which might contain escaped double quotes themselves. Now I read the entire content into a string.

Comment: then you should be able to do this with a simple string.Replace Function I will post a working example

Comment: I have fixed your issue with a simple string.Replace function

Comment: Do you have any idea, why Regex.Split returned me the string array I mentioned?

Comment: I don't use Regexc normally so I can't answer that question look how simple the string.Replace method is..also is there a cardinal rule that you `must use RegEx` I would suggest reading the `RegEx.Split()` function documentation and seeing how their split functions work..

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what your attempting to do, but I believe it is as follows:

```
    var content = "\"abc\", \"a\\\"b\\\"c\"";
    var filter = Regex.Split(content, @"(?<=[,\s]\"")(.*?)(?=\"")");
    foreach(var item in filter)
        Console.WriteLine(item);
```

The output would be as follows:

- "abc", "
- a\
- "b\"c"

This should ignore your escape, but grab items within a quote even as nested as you've noticed.

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: This is indeed the problem I am trying to solve, but your solution didn't yield the results you expected. I am also interested in understanding how Regex.Split ended up giving me the string I was talking about.

Comment: @user2528242 Will there always be a `,` to separate the value?  If so, why don't you split on that.  It didn't work because I modified the content with single quote not double, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

```
var content = "\"abc\", \"a\\\"b\\\"c\"";
var spltContent = content.Split(new[] {@"\\\"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

this will be your out put
`"\"abc\", \"a\\\"b\\\"c\""`

Answer (score 0):

According to the [StringSplitOptions "Remarks" section](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringsplitoptions%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> The String.Split method returns an array of the substrings in a given string that are delimited by specified characters or strings. Adjacent delimiters yield an array element that contains an empty string (""). The values of the StringSplitOptions enumeration specify whether an array element that contains an empty string is included in the returned array.

As for working around this quirk, MethodMan has the right idea: pass the `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` argument to `Split()` to remove those entries.